# Clarification about the best way to structure tkinter pages

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, tkinter

This is a quick question but I can't seem to find an answer I understand.

I'm building a "simple" 3 page "app" with `tkinter` and I have been building each page as a separate class in a separate `.py` document. I thought that this would be the best way to make sure that no single `.py` document was crazy long as a result of making each page a frame within the `__init__` of a big file.

I'm new to `tkinter` (and relatively new to python) so I'm worried that I've made a mistake.

should each page I want the user to move between be a frame within the larger class or is it ok to have each page be a class in a seperate `.py` document.

The code below is an example of how I've built the first page the user "should" see.

```
    from tkinter import *
    import tkinter as tk


    class FrontPage:
        """This is a class to make the front page"""
        def __init__(self, master):
            self.master = master
            master.title = "Global Frequency"
            self.input = tk.StringVar()


            self.mainframe = tk.Frame(
                master
            ).pack()

            self.name_label = tk.Label(
                self.mainframe,
                text="Welcome agent:",
                font=("Courier", 20),
            )
            self.name_label.pack()

            self.inst_label1 = tk.Label(
                self.mainframe,
                text = "Agent's name:", 
                font = ("Courier", 15),
                bd = 20,
            )
            self.inst_label1.place(
                relx = 0.5,
                rely = 0.3,             
                anchor = 'n'
            )


            self.name_entry = tk.Entry(
                self.mainframe,
                textvariable = self.input,
                justify = CENTER
            )
            self.name_entry.place(
                relx = 0.5,
                rely = 0.37,
                anchor = 'n'
            )

            self.ent_btn = tk.Button(
                self.mainframe,
                text = "Save",
                font = ("Courier", 15),
                command = lambda: self.getname()
            ).place(
                relx = 0.5,
                rely = 0.43,
                anchor = 'n'
            )

            self.btn_frame = tk.Frame(
                self.mainframe,
                height = 200,
                width = 395,
                bd = 4,
                relief = GROOVE
            ).place(
                relx = 0.5,
                rely = 0.6,
                anchor = 'n'
            )

            self.rules_btn = tk.Button(self.mainframe,
                text = "RULES",
                font=("Courier", 15),
            )
            self.rules_btn.place(
                relx = 0.25,
                rely = 0.66,
                anchor = 'n',
                height = 120,
                width = 170
            )

            self.con_btn = tk.Button(self.mainframe,
                text = "DEPLOY",
                font=("Courier", 15),
                justify=CENTER, 
            )
            self.con_btn.place(
                relx = 0.75,
                rely = 0.66,
                anchor = 'n',
                height = 120,
                width = 170
            )

        def getname(self):
            self.input.set(
                self.name_entry.get()
            )







    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("400x600")
    gui = FrontPage(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I think I'm making a mistake in the last few lines where I call the tkinter mainloop, but thats probably just going to cunfuse me for now.

really my question is just:
do I need to take all this code and turn it into a second frame in my main app .py file.

As I said above, thanks again for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to rewrite all your code; what you should do, is write the second page in a `tk.Frame`, then extract a `GUI` class from the `FrontPage`, and use it to navigate the pages.

You could consider extracting the navbar into its own class too.

All your gui pages can be in separate files; in the `GUI` module, you can import the classes corresponding to each page, and launch the gui.

Maybe something like this, where I added a second page, and a navigation frame.
(I also [blackified](https://black.now.sh/) the formatting of your code)

```
import tkinter as tk


class GUI(tk.Tk):
    """this is the app
    it inherits from tk.Tk
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "Global Frequency"
        self.geometry("400x600")

        self.navig_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.first_btn = tk.Button(
            self.navig_frame,
            text="show_first",
            command=self.show_first,
        )
        self.first_btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.second_btn = tk.Button(
            self.navig_frame,
            text="show_second",
            command=self.show_second,
        )
        self.second_btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.navig_frame.pack()

        self.front = FrontPage(self)
        self.front.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.second = SecondPage(self)

    def show_first(self):
        self.second.pack_forget()
        self.front.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

    def show_second(self):
        self.front.pack_forget()
        self.second.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)


class FrontPage(tk.Frame):
    """This is a class to make the front page
    it inherits from tk.Frame
    """

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        super().__init__(self.master)
        self.input = tk.StringVar()

        self.mainframe = tk.Frame(self)
        self.mainframe.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.name_label = tk.Label(
            self.mainframe,
            text="Welcome agent:",
            font=("Courier", 20),
        )
        self.name_label.pack()

        self.inst_label1 = tk.Label(
            self.mainframe,
            text="Agent's name:",
            font=("Courier", 15),
            bd=20,
        )
        self.inst_label1.place(
            relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor="n"
        )

        self.name_entry = tk.Entry(
            self.mainframe,
            textvariable=self.input,
            justify=tk.CENTER,
        )
        self.name_entry.place(
            relx=0.5, rely=0.37, anchor="n"
        )

        self.ent_btn = tk.Button(
            self.mainframe,
            text="Save",
            font=("Courier", 15),
            command=lambda: self.getname(),
        )
        self.ent_btn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.43, anchor="n")

        self.btn_frame = tk.Frame(
            self.mainframe,
            height=200,
            width=395,
            bd=4,
            relief=tk.GROOVE,
        )
        self.btn_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor="n")

        self.rules_btn = tk.Button(
            self.mainframe,
            text="RULES",
            font=("Courier", 15),
        )
        self.rules_btn.place(
            relx=0.25,
            rely=0.66,
            anchor="n",
            height=120,
            width=170,
        )

        self.con_btn = tk.Button(
            self.mainframe,
            text="DEPLOY",
            font=("Courier", 15),
            justify=tk.CENTER,
        )
        self.con_btn.place(
            relx=0.75,
            rely=0.66,
            anchor="n",
            height=120,
            width=170,
        )

    def getname(self):
        self.input.set(self.name_entry.get())


class SecondPage(tk.Frame):
    """This is a class to make the second page
    it inherits from tk.Frame
    """

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        super().__init__(self.master)
        self.input = tk.StringVar()

        self.mainframe = tk.Frame(self)
        self.mainframe.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.label = tk.Label(
            self.mainframe, text="second page"
        )
        self.label.pack()


gui = GUI()
gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is brilliant (and a big relief) thanks, I didn't want to have to reformat everything massively, but would have if needed. 

Can I ask, since you've given such a cool answer here, If i want to pass information from FrontPage() to SecondPage(), how would I call that? when I try it so far i just get None.

Thanks a million again for the help.

Comment: I want to take the text from the entry box (which I have called self.input = tk.StringVar()) on frontpage and pass it as text into a label on the second page. I'm still getting triped up on passing between classes.

Answer (score -1):

How you decide to organize your code is a matter of your own convenience. The important thing is that you can easily navigate you code.

There are, however, a few problems:

**Coding style:**

```
self.mainframe = tk.Frame(
    master
).pack()
```

Python coders (I have seen) would usually write the code as:

```
self.mainframe = tk.Frame(master).pack()
```

There is nothing wrong with your style but other Python coders may find it difficult to read as it's not in the usual way. Yes, it is [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compliant but it takes up much more space than is necessary.

**Methods returning `None`:**

The return from a statement will be the return from the last method applied, so the line below will assign `None` to the name `self.mainframe` as `pack()` returns `None`:

```
self.mainframe = tk.Frame(master).pack()
```

You do this in a couple of places.

```
self.mainframe
self.ent_btn
self.btn_frame
```

**Using place():**

Using `place()` makes your design react poorly to size changes and can be difficult to maintain for larger designs.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and all this is useful. However, my issue is that I'm having trouble getting each page to open on its own and then navigating through each one, and I'm worried that this might be because I've ordered the code. I'm guessing from your answer that this isn't the reason I'm having my problem so I'll keep looking.